# How to connect to postgresql google cloud sql instance? Need to import postgresql dump using pg_restore command

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a google cloud sql postgresql instance. When I try to import postgresql dump I get following error.

[image]

I am able to connect to instance with the command given below.

```
gcloud sql connect instance-name --user postgres
```

It takes me to the psql command line client where I can not use database restore command like **pg_restore**

Does anyone have an idea on how can I actually connect to Google Cloud SQL instance so that I can perform operation such as pg_restore?

Comment: Near the gift icon, in the upper right corner, you have the command prompt button.
That will allow you to connect to the console so you could be abble to launch pg_restore...

Answer (score 7):

if you need **pg_restore** can simply use:

`gcloud sql connect instance-name --user postgres < dbbackup.sql`

where *dbbackup.sql* is a file obtained from:

`pg_dump olddb  --format=plain --no-owner -v >> dbbackup.sql`

Comment: Where does this file exactly created at ? "dbbackup.sql"

Comment: This will import into the postgres database, you need to add PGDATABASE=yourdb to the gcloud command to specify your database. Note that despite google's docs, you CANNOT specify the database on the command line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47299696/specifying-the-db-to-connect-with-gcloud-sql